# "Hello World".ShowDialog() not possible in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

Say I have an extension method on *String* **`ShowDialog`**, that displays a mesagebox with the specified string.

Why I cant do now

```
"Hello World".ShowDialog()
```

and need to play with

```
Call "Hello World".ShowDialog()
```

or

```
CStr("Hello World").ShowDialog()
```

or even

```
Dim myString = "Hello World"
myString.ShowDialog()
```

or even

```
If "Hello World".ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    CStr("Thank You!").ShowDialog()
End If
```

Comment: What compiler error are you getting?

Comment: Tim Schmelter, Why do You talk about C#, when the question is for VB.NET?

Comment: Tim, this is a specific behavior of VB.NET, in C# it works as it should, not in VB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.Net, expressions have to start with an identifier.

```
"Hello World".ShowDialog()
```

does not start with an identifier, hence you have to use the [`Call` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You typically use the Call keyword when the called expression doesn’t start with an identifier. Use of the Call keyword for other uses isn’t recommended.

Comment: Do you agree that this is ugly and is not very well thought out?

Comment: @serhio I agree it totally sucks :-)

Comment: I once had complaint about that on VS-Feedback, but "they" dont see that uglyness ...